# consulta lista de campos mayor a 6 digitos php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla,

tabla: columna referencia

```
abc
abcd
abcdef
123
1234567
```

dentro de ella una columna llamada referencia, y necesito saber cuantas celdas tiene mas de 6 caracteres,

1-un contador de cuantos campos de la columna referencia tiene mas de 6 caracteres en este ejemplo debe montar en pantalla el resultado del **contador = 2**

2 Generar una lista con un while bajo la condicion que si es 6 o mayor la cantidad de caracteres

$consulta_mas_de_6_query = "select * from " . TABLE . " where ?????? ";

solo pinte estas dos referencias ya que tienen 6 caracteres o mas para obtener este resultado:

```
abcdef
1234567
```

conozco esta funcion pero creo que no es la adecuada:

```
$str = $consulta_mas_de_6_query['referencia']; 
echo strlen($str);
```

Comment: Puedes obtener directamente las que tengan más de 6 caracteres con esta consulta: **`SELECT referencia FROM tuTabla WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) > 6`** Ahí tendrás todas las filas que cumplan esa condición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySQL existe la función `CHAR_LENGTH` para contar el tamaño de una cadena. Su sintaxis es `CHAR_LENGHT(str)`.

[Según la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length):

> Returns the length of the string `str`, measured in characters. A
>   multibyte character counts as a single character. This means that for
>   a string containing five 2-byte characters, `LENGTH()` returns 10,
>   whereas `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns 5.
>
> ---
>
> Devuelve la longitud de la cadena `str`, medida en caracteres. Un
>   carácter multibyte cuenta como un solo carácter. Esto significa que
>   para una cadena que contiene cinco caracteres de 2 bytes, `LENGTH ()`
>   devuelve 10, mientras que `CHAR_LENGTH ()` devuelve 5.

Puedes usarla en el `WHERE` para obtener solamente las filas que tengan en `referencia` más de 6 caracteres:

```
SELECT referencia FROM tuTabla WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) > 6;
```

Ten en cuenta lo que dice de las cadenas multibyte. Si quieres que te cuente bit a bit, debes usar `LENGHT`.